# C# serial port connection class accessing from main form, on return to main form the connection has stopped or out of context?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, serial-port

```
                Sensor angle1 = new Sensor(portA, "Connect");
                Sensor angle2 = new Sensor(out ConnectionAstatus);
```

This is on my main page to access this class, in debugging it connects but once the ConnectionAstatus is checked then there is no connection, it seems to disconnect once leaves the class?

Comment: You have to start debugging as to why you are getting the error. Also, your code does not show enough information for other people to help you.

Comment: What does `disconnect once leaves the class` mean? Could you provide a simple demo that can reproduce this issue? Refer to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).